# Check that only root can edit a script before executing it

Tags: bash, shell-script, security, root

I have a script that needs to run as root. It also has a configuration file which is read using source:

```
source conf.sh
```

I would like to check that normal user can't edit `conf.sh` and therefore get root access.

I can check who's the file owner and what permissions group and others have:

```
if [[ "$(stat -c "%a" conf.sh | egrep ".2.|.3.|.6.|.7.|..2|..3|..6|..7")" != "" ]] || [[ "$(stat -c "%u" conf.sh)" != "0" ]]; then
    #don't execute the file"
fi
```

Am I missing anything here? Are there any best practices?

Comment: You also need to check all the path components for write access only to root.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas That's no enough. This approach is fundamentally flawed. There's a non-negligible chance that someone could find another file on the system that belongs to root (like anything in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin`) and causes all kinds of havoc when invoked in the wrong context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it with arithmetic evaluation:

```
if [[ $(stat -c '%u' conf.sh) -ne 0 -o \
      $(( $(stat -c '%a' conf.sh) & 0044)) -ne 0 ]]; then
    # file's owner is not root or file is writable by group or world
fi
```

Comment: There's also filesystem ACLs to consider.